# Issue while importing wt/json/bson files in Studio 3T

Tags: mongodb

How can I import .wt(WiredTiger) files in Studio 3T MongoDB.
Also I am not able to import json files in Studio 3T.
It is showing some erroes like this

2024-02-14 15:48:54:  Import
Importing 1 unit finished: 0 completed successfully, 1 failed.
Total time: 00:00:00.071
Import JSON [JSON] : JSON parse error at position 0: Expecting an opening '{':  A�

I tried importing as json, bson and wt files in Studio 3T, it is not accepting it.
I also tried converting the wt files to json, but to no avail. Please help !

Comment: You cannot import .wt files into a MongoDB. When you need to restore a database then you must copy **all** files from `dbPath` to new location. You can import only JSON or CSV data (for example with `mongoimport`) or a dump with `mongorestore`

Comment: Is there any way to convert these .wt files to json. I am not able open these files or even convert them online to json/csv format. Also I am running MongoDB instance using Docker.

Comment: What is not clear when I write "You cannot import .wt files into a MongoDB"? No, I am not aware of any tool which can convert a .wt file into a format you could insert into MongoDB.